# Re-enable "Externally added files can be added to Git" notification in PyCharm

Tags: version-control, pycharm

There's a popup that occurs in PyCharm to let you manually add externally-created files to VCS. This is very convenient for e.g. Django migrations, which I often forget to commit otherwise. Unfortunately, I accidentally clicked the "Don't show again" button on the popup, and I cannot seem to find the setting to re-enable it, nor have searches turned up results on re-enabling it.

I still have "VCS important messages" enabled under notifications, which I believe this falls under.

How can I re-enable this popup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i fix the same problem like this:
File→Setting→Version Control→Confirmation→
"When files are created":"☑Show "